# How to show tax price using crystal report based on formula?

Tags: variables, crystal-reports

there's a 3 variable.

```
Inclusive Price = Value from Stored Procedure
Base Price = Inclusive Price / 1.1
Tax Price = Inclusive Price - Base Price
```

and i have transformed that variable into a code

```
dim tax_price as int,dim base_price as int
base_price := {r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net}/1.1;
tax_price := {r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net} - taxnya;
return tax_price
```

and still it has no result.

how can i make it work ?

Comment: are you doing it in crystal as a standalone application or in coding?

Comment: @Siva i'm doing it on my formula editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// {@tax_price}
{r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net} - ({r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net}/1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even Craig formula will work but if want to store in variables then below is the code.

```
Local Numbervar tax_price;
Local Numbervar base_price;
base_price := {r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net}/1.1;
tax_price := {r_sa_pesanan_lampiran;1.total_net} - base_price;
tax_price;
```